# Pandas: filling missing values with another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas: filling missing values with another column

Currently the dataframe is:

| Val1 | Val2 |
| --- | --- |
| Cambridge | MA |
| NAN | FL |
| Washington | DC |
| Washington | NAN |
| Miami | FL |
| NAN | DC |
| Washington | DC |
| Miami | FL |

The desired output is:

| Val1 | Val2 |
| --- | --- |
| Cambridge | MA |
| Miami | FL |
| Washington | DC |
| Washington | DC |
| Miami | FL |
| Washington | DC |
| Washington | DC |
| Miami | FL |

Thanks

Comment: So how should it decide, e.g. that Val2's value of FL means that Val1 should be Miami? There are multiple cities in Florida. Are you looking for the biggest city? This question could use some explanation.

Comment: I the value should pull from another row in the dataset. Miami FL is in one of the rows below

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
df['Val1'] = df.groupby('Val2').bfill().ffill()
df['Val2'] = df.groupby('Val1').bfill().ffill()
```